# How to sort a collection of objects by one of it's properties

Tags: vb.net, sorting

So there is a class named Article with 2 properties

```
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Price As Decimal
```

Now I made another class that contains a single property

```
Public Property Articles As Article()
```

This is supposed to be some kind of repository and it works perfectly good for what it is supposed to do however now I have to sort this collection by one of the properties, once by name and once by price without losing the connection between the names and prices (it has to remember a beer costs 2$ and an apple 1$ for example).

Comment: Wow, and the answer turned out to be this simple.
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx) with a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate; but be aware that your original array will be sorted.

```
Array.Sort(Articles, Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))
```

If you want to sort your array on multiple values (or you want to keep the original array), you could use the [`IEnumerable(Of T).OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method (chained with [`IEnumerable(Of T).ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx)).

```
' Either store the result in the current Articles variable or a new one
Dim sortedArray As Article() = Articles.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Name) _
                               .ThenBy(Function(a) a.Price) _
                               .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sort your array.  For example, to sort by price:

```
Array.Sort(Articles, Function(a1, a2) a1.Price.CompareTo(a2.Price))
```